# How to make onItemClick work with customCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, onitemclick

I have been unable to get clickOnItem to work from a list populated from a customCursorAdapter.  I have read all of the design docs, and posts relating to this and related areas, but all attempts have failed. Help please!

The list populates fine, but when I click on a list item I get the error "No such method exception" onItemClick [class android.view.View]

I am using the following code to output a set of data from a database query:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListTripsActivity extends Activity
{

    private CustomCursorAdapter customAdapter;
    private DbHelper databaseHelper;
    private static final int ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private ListView listView;     
    private static final String TAG = ListTripsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);  
        databaseHelper = new DbHelper(this);                       
        customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this, databaseHelper.getTripList(DbHelper.DESC), 0);    
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); 
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter); 

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "clicked on item: " + position);
            }
        });  
    }
```

My activity_list.xml is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
               android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

     <!-- This ListView is populated by customCursorAdapter -->
     <!-- The content layout is defined by row_layout.xml   -->

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"              
              android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Change Name"
            android:onClick="onClickEnterData"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

The row_layout.xml follows, and it is the 2 TextView items that I am trying to click on.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

   <EditText  android:id="@+id/activityId"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="12sp"
              android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/activityName"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:inputType="text"
              android:textSize="12sp"
              android:paddingBottom="5dp"
              android:imeOptions="actionSend" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/startDate"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:onClick="onItemClick"                
              android:clickable="true"  
              android:textSize="12sp"
              android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/endDate"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:onClick="onItemClick"                
              android:clickable="true"
              android:textSize="12sp"
              android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: where is this `listview.setAdapter(customAdapter)` statement.

Answer (score 0):

@Raghunandan Is right. You took this code from some example where they are using ListActivity and they are using setAdapter to assign adapter to listView.

Instead of

```
setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

use

```
listview.setAdapter(customAdapter)
```

Comment: I made the change agreed by you and @Raghunandan but still get the identical error

Comment: Try to remove following attributes from row layout xml:
android:onClick="onItemClick"                
android:clickable="true"

Comment: When I remove either or both of these XML lines, there is no interface response to clicking on the item

Comment: If I understood you correct, you would like to add onClickListener for list item, not for specific element in that item. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  If I can get it to my method: public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) , the arguments will tell me what was clicked.